# best index type for uuid in postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, index, uuid

I realize a similar question has been asked multiple times but all the ones I can find are from 2014/2015 and many versions of postgres ago.

I'm on postgres 11. I'm introducing a new primary key for a table of type `uuid`. I see that since postgres 10, `hash` index types are in pretty good shape ( e.g. http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2017/09/postgresqls-hash-indexes-are-now-cool.html ), and I'm wondering if it's the better choice for a `uuid` key in postgres these days?

---

**Update** I realize I'm missing part of the use case which impacts this question.

My primary use case is that I previously had a composite primary key and am replacing it with a UUID for easy joins and to not have to propagate the primary key's data to other tables.

In this sense, I'm likely to want create the primary key using `INCLUDE (composite, fields, here)` which is only supported for `btree` index types. So in that sense, I have my answer.

I am still curious about a 'generic' use case of simply wanting rapid access to looking up a value by its primary key, however.

Comment: To not answer your question, I suggest you use [ULIDs](https://github.com/ulid/spec) instead of UUIDs if you are concerned about your index. I elaborate [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/274038).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *My primary use case is that I previously had a composite primary key
>   and am replacing it with a UUID for easy joins and to not have to
>   propagate the primary key's data to other tables.*

A hash index wouldn't work for that: it can't enforce uniqueness, therefore it can't be used to support a primary key. As mentioned in the [v11 documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/indexes-unique.html):

> **Currently, only B-tree indexes can be declared unique.**

Comment: That's an excellent point, thank you.